# Testing swipe on responsive website using Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test a swipe across an image gallery on a responsive website. On a mobile device it would be a finger swipe, using a desktop browser it functions the same with a mouse click/hold/drag. It's the desktop browser functionality I'm trying to replicate.

The code I have is:

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Properties.Settings.Default.TestPage);

var mainImage = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".main-image"));

var imageAcross = (mainImage.Size.Width / 4 ) * 3;
var imageDown = mainImage.Size.Height/2;

var builder = new Actions(Driver);

builder.MoveToElement(mainImage, imageAcross, imageDown).ClickAndHold().Build().Perform();

TakeScreenshot(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);

builder.MoveByOffset(-imageDown, 0).Release().Build().Perform();

TakeScreenshot(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
```

The `TakeScreenshot` function, as the name suggests, saves a screenshot. I take one before and after the move.

The first `builder.MoveToElement` places the cursor where I would expect and after the `builder.MoveByOffset` the cursor has moved as expected. However the swipe didn't change the gallery image. It's as if the `ClickAndHold` was ignored.

The CSS element `.main-image` is a div tag that has Javascript attached that changes an image within it on the swipe. The browser I'm using for testing is PhantomJS.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Or any suggestions on how to get the swipe to work?